# Use Snackbar on Android TV Leanback theme

Tags: android, android-tv, android-snackbar

I am developing app for Android TV and using Theme.Leanback for my main activity. I am trying to show Snackbar and it shows following error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.

Is there any work-around? If not, what is the recommended way of showing message on Android TV (besides using Toast)?

Comment: Yes you can use *Toast* message in *Leanback* android. And could you please show your code so that i can suggest you.

Answer (score 1):

The Snackbar is part of the AppCompat library, meaning it is dependent on the AppCompat theme to display correctly.

If you want to display a message in a Leanback app, you should not use the Snackbar because TVs don't have the same interaction experience as on a phone. The Leanback theme provides a different set of widgets optimized for TV apps.

Alternative ways to show messages on a TV are using a `Toast` or using an `AlertDialog` depending on how you want to display the message.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to use snackbar. You need to add

```
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorSecondary</item>
```

Into your theme, in place where you want to call snackbar